# MFC used in library causing error console application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to use Task Schedule throulg Visual c++. I'm using Ctask.h (from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13089/Harnessing-the-task-scheduler))
to do the task. However, when I build the solution (using Visual Studio 11), it says

```
fatal error C1189: #error :  Please use the /MD switch for _AFXDLL builds
```

When I switch to /MD, it gives this error

```
ConsoleApplication12.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CTask::CTask(void)" (??0CTask@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _wmain
1>ConsoleApplication12.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall CTask::SetStartDateTime(class ATL::CTime const &)" (?SetStartDateTime@CTask@@QAEXABVCTime@ATL@@@Z) referenced in function _wmain
1>ConsoleApplication12.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall CTask::SetFrequency(enum CTask::ETaskFrequency)" (?SetFrequency@CTask@@QAEXW4ETaskFrequency@1@@Z) referenced in function _wmain
1>ConsoleApplication12.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall CTask::SetProgram(wchar_t const *)" (?SetProgram@CTask@@QAEXPB_W@Z) referenced in function _wmain
1>ConsoleApplication12.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall CTask::SetAccountName(wchar_t const *)" (?SetAccountName@CTask@@QAEXPB_W@Z) referenced in function _wmain
1>ConsoleApplication12.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall CTask::SaveTask(wchar_t const *,int)const " (?SaveTask@CTask@@QBEJPB_WH@Z) referenced in function _wmain
1>ConsoleApplication12.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall CTask::~CTask(void)" (??1CTask@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _wmain
```

same is the case with other linking option. This is thecode I've typed:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CTask.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;




int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CTask task;
    CTime time(2013, 03, 15, 7, 11, 0);
    LPCTSTR sTaskName( L"Task Name" );

    BOOL replace = TRUE;

    task.SetProgram( L"E:\\aaa.txt" );
    task.SetAccountName( L"harshilsharma63" );
    task.SetStartDateTime( time );
    task.SetFrequency( CTask::freqOnce );

    if( S_OK == task.SaveTask( sTaskName, replace))
    {
        cout << "task successfully created!";
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "task creation failed!";
        return 1;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I have already set "Use MFC in" to "Use MFC in shared DLL".

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any indication that you actually have put the CTask.cpp into your project. Including the header only will result in the linker errors you see, you need the .cpp, too.

Answer (score 1):

You need add to your project the CTask.cpp as well as CTask.h. The original project http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13089/Harnessing-the-task-scheduler can be compiled without any trouble - I just checked it!

Comment: How do I include the .cpp file? I mean, I added #include "CTask.cpp" but that did not work. Is there some other way to add .cpp files?

Comment: Right click in the Projects browser on the parent directory 
of your source files and selected "Add Existing Item" -> CTask.cpp

Comment: I added CTask.cpp to the project and it appeared in Source Files in solution explorer. But when I built it, it gave the error: Cannot open include file: 'MyTaskDemo.h': No such file or directory

Wnen I added MyTaskDemo.h, then it gave this error: include 'stdafx.h' before including this file for PCH

in CTask.cpp even though stdafx.h was included in it's code.

Comment: You use the option "Precompiled header", it expect the 'stdafx.h' been included on the very first place !

Comment: So, I created a new project and disabled the option to use "Precompiled headers", but the same error is coming even now. Sorry if I'm asking very basic questions, but I don't have much experience in such multi-file work.

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7fz9ckx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx